# Does sub-orchestrator in azure durable functions have its own execution history?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I have the main orchestrator and in the orchestrator, I have multiple calls to sub-orchestrators.
The data is quite massive so I would like to avoid having a massive execution history table.
So is execution history divided by sub-orchestrator instances? How do I check it?

Comment: Are you trying to avoid heavy application insight log data?

Comment: @SuryasriKamini-MT yes